# Package incompatibilites: etoolbox, hyperref, and bm, standalone?

Tags: macros, hyperref, incompatibility, etoolbox, standalone

I am trying to transition to using the `etoolbox` package, but seem to have run into some difficulties and they appear related to the `hyperref` and `bm` packages which to me seem totally unrelated.  The MWE example compiles since `\RemoveEToolbox` is defined and shows that there is no apparent problem before `etoolbox` was used.

Commenting out the `\def\RemoveEToolbox{}` line produces two problems:

1. With both the `\renewcommand`, and the `usepackage{hyperref}` commented, this results in **"Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before \bm@test@token was complete"**.
2. Including the `usepackage{hyperref}` (with `\renewcommand` commented) results in **"Undefined control  sequence. \Call@AtVeryEndDocument ...cumentHook \@undefined"**

But if uncomment the `\renewcommand{\bm}{#1}` line (effectively doing without any `\bm`), then this seems to compile.

I have been using this for a while now and things appeared to have been working fine, but now that I attempt to use `etoolbox` I seem to run into problems.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\RemoveEToolbox{}% Shows that this works fine without {etoolbox}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}

\ifdefined\RemoveEToolbox
    \newcommand*{\iftoggle}[3]{#2}% Default to true value of "if"
\else
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newtoggle{paper}
    \toggletrue{paper}

    %\renewcommand{\bm}[1]{#1}% Why can't I have a normal \bm with {etoolbox}?
\fi

% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This document is intended for 
\iftoggle{paper}{paper}{electronic}
distribution.

\bm{\textcolor{blue}{Solve $x^2-1=0$}}

\begin{align*}
    a &= b\\
    \iftoggle{paper}{
        c &= d\\
    }{}
    e &= f\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issues is that both the `standalone` class and the `etoolbox` package redefine the `document` environment. This causes a clash. You can avoid this by loading `etoolbox` before the class using `\RequirePackage`. I will try to support the normal of this package, but it will take a while until I have to time to release a new version of `standalone`.

#### Workaround:

```
\def\RemoveEToolbox{}% Shows that this works fine without {etoolbox}

\ifdefined\RemoveEToolbox
    \newcommand*{\iftoggle}[3]{#2}% Default to true value of "if"
\else
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \newtoggle{paper}
    \toggletrue{paper}

    %\renewcommand{\bm}[1]{#1}% Why can't I have a normal \bm with {etoolbox}?
\fi

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}

% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This document is intended for 
\iftoggle{paper}{paper}{electronic}
distribution.

\bm{\textcolor{blue}{Solve $x^2-1=0$}}

\begin{align*}
    a &= b\\
    \iftoggle{paper}{
        c &= d\\
    }{}
    e &= f\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

#### Update 2011/12/21

The new version 1.0 of `standalone` works fine with `etoolbox`, due to a changed way to patch the `document` environment. However, the new default settings ignore paragraph breaks, so you will a problem with `align*`.
You can fix easily this by using the `varwidth` class option.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Wonder if this is related to the other problem with `standalone` that I emailed you.

Comment: @Peter: I changed the package and class code now to patch the `document` environment differently. This fixes the issue.

Answer (score 10):

(Martin has posted an answer, but there is a bit more to this!) The problem arises due to an issue with the definition of `\@@end`. This is where the LaTeX kernel stores the TeX `\end` primitive (so that `\end` can be reused for environments). The `bm` package does various tests for `\@@end` which rely on it being the primitive. What is happening is that `etoolbox` does

```
\patchcmd\enddocument
  {\deadcycles}
  {\let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@afterenddocumenthook
   \deadcycles}
  {}
  {\let\etb@@end\@@end
   \def\@@end{%
     \let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
     \@afterenddocumenthook
     \etb@@end}}
```

which tries to patch `\enddocument`, and if it cannot then alters the definition of `\@@end`. In the standard classes, the patch works (it looks for `\deadcycles`), and so all is well. On the other hand, this fails for `standalone` as it redefines `\enddocument` as

```
\def\sa@@enddocument{%
  %\let\document\sa@orig@document
  \let\enddocument\sa@orig@enddocument
  \endinput
}
```

So in this case, `etoolbox` does it's 'fall-back' patch, and then the tests in `bm` fail.

If you do not need the end-document hook, the fix is easy

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@end\etb@end
\makeatother
```

---

I have now taken up maintenance of `etoolbox` and a [fix has been applied to the code](https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/commit/71764e352ceb8e062a21548edc9b485d79daee41). The approach now taken is to delay redefining `\@@end` as late as possible using the `\AtEndDocument` hook.

Comment: Under what cases would I need the end-document hook? If this involved I can post a follow up question.

Comment: @Peter It is more likely that some other package might want it than you would yourself. A hook right at the end of the document is useful for some processes which work between LaTeX runs, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I will try to support the patch commands. Note that the code you show is from the `standalone` *package*, not the class which is used here. However, the class code is quite similar.

Comment: @Martin: I did a quick read through the code, and assumed that with a class and a package that the 'payload' was in the later, with the class loading the package.

Comment: @Joseph: Used to be the case, but they are now separated. However, you can also load both (if you want to include a standalone inside another). Both patch the `document` environment and therefore both have this issue anyway.