# Incompatibility between etextools and etoolbox command \dolistloop (\forlistloop)?

Tags: incompatibility, etoolbox

The following code uses the `etoolbox` package to convert a list `a,b,c` into an internal list (called `\mylist`) and then typesets that with colons: `a:b:c:`.  However, when I load the `etextools` package (by uncommenting the second line), I get no list output.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{etextools}
\begin{document}
A list:
\def\mylist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\mylist}{a,b,c}
\def\do#1{#1:}
\dolistloop{\mylist}
\end{document}
```

I suspect it is is a bug since `etextools` claims to depend on `etoolbox`.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  In either case, how can I use `\dolistloop` with 
`etextools` (which I want for goodies like `\expandnext`)?

### Notes

- `\show\mylist` produces the same output `a|b|c|` in both cases, so the problem is with `\dolistloop` which expands to `\forlistloop\do`
- The `\forlistloop` command becomes substantially more complicated when `etextools` is used.
- [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22995/package-incompatibilites-etoolbox-hyperref-and-bm-standalone) might be relevant (but not obviously).

Comment: The `\DeclareCmdListParser\listloop{|}` command in `etextools.sty` is responsible for changing `\forlistloop`.  Not sure yet why this breaks the behaviour.

Comment: If one is committed to using `etextools`, then `\listloop{\mylist}` works where `\dolistloop{\mylist}` fails.  I would still like code that works with and without `etextools`.

Comment: Just a note that this bug [has been noticed before](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/VRrFB4ll5n0/kAlsBWKEcOgJ).  I also sent a message to Florent Chervet mentioning this bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a bug in the `etextools` package. In fact, `\forlistloop` is currently redefined in a way incompatible with the `etoolbox` package. Hence, try:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\origforlistloop\forlistloop
\usepackage{etextools}
\let\forlistloop\origforlistloop
```

Comment: This does not explain what the problem is, but is a reasonable practical solution (though may create other issues with ``etextools``).  Hopefully the maintainer will step in, confirm the bug, and have a suggestion for fixing it.

Comment: @mforbes: Both the `etoolbox` package and the `etextools` package define `\forlistloop`, but unfortunately not with the same argument signature. This is the problem.

Comment: @mforbes: If you need the `\dolistloop` of the `etoolbox` package, but otherwise the `\forlistloop` of the `etextools` package don’t restore `\forlistloop` and use `\patchcmd` to replace `\forlistloop` with `\origforlistloop` in the definition of `\dolistloop`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use *catoptions* package, you can do

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % you may load this if you like
%\usepackage{etextools} % load if you like
\usepackage{catoptions}

\begin{document}
% Add these elements to list container \mylist:
\docommalist{a,b,c}{\cptaddtolist\mylist{#1}}

% User callback for every item in \mylist. Don't print the last colon (:):
\def\mydo#1{#1\iflastindris\else:\fi}

% Do the looping over elements of \mylist. The star (*) form of \indrisloop expects
% a macro whose top level expansion contains the list items:
\indrisloop*\mylist\mydo
\end{document}
```