# biblatex and autonum don't work together

Tags: biblatex, errors, incompatibility, autonum

`biblatex` and `autonum` don't seem to work together in the newest version. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
0 File ended while scanning use of \ettl@for@do1
0 pdflatex: \pdfmatch: repetition-operator operand invalid pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: \pdfmatch: repetition-operator operand invalid)Runaway argument?{{\blx@bibdata@i {\blx@tempb }}\blx@bibfiles \eappto \blx@tempa {\blx@xml@comme
```

After commenting out either `biblatex` or `autonum`, the errors disappear.

Comment: I can confirm this

Comment: The problem is in the fact that `autonum` uses `etextools` that takes the liberty of redefining `\forlistloop` in a way that is incompatible with what `biblatex` expects. I don't recommend using `etextools`, nor any package relying on it.

Comment: So far `autonum` (and some `mathtools` package option) are the only ways of achieving the desired automatic equation numbering, right?

Comment: @Deniz I think so; but I also think that numbering only the referenced equations is a bad idea.

Comment: @egreg That is highly context-dependent. But thanks for pointing out the problem so fast - I guess the autonum package will need to be changed?

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/669 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/383. Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431965/35864

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that `autonum` uses `etextools`. Indeed, the error is reproducible also with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{etextools}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `etextools` redefines `\forlistloop` in a way that is incompatible with what `biblatex` expects.

From what I see in `autonum.sty`, `\forlistloop` is not used, so it could be safe restoring it to the value `biblatex` is expecting. But there's no guarantee that other macros of `biblatex` use constructs made buggy by `etextools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\let\etoolboxforlistloop\forlistloop % save the good meaning of \forlistloop
\usepackage{autonum}
\let\forlistloop\etoolboxforlistloop % restore the good meaning of \forlistloop


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A\label{A}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B\label{B}
\end{equation}

\ref{A}

\begin{equation}\label{C}
\begin{split} A\\ b \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The functionality of `autonum` seems to be OK.

See also [Incompatibility between etextools and etoolbox command \dolistloop (\forlistloop)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49556/incompatibility-between-etextools-and-etoolbox-command-dolistloop-forlistloop)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Before we finish this: If I add the following `split` environment (without any labels/references), I get several errors, and again, only in connection with both `autonum` and `biblatex`.

    `\begin{equation} \begin{split} A\\ b \end{split} \end{equation}`

How do I correctly address this here on StackExchange? As a new question?

Comment: @Deniz Sorry, with `split` some features of `etextools` are indeed used. I've changed into another fix

Comment: Now it still doesn't work when a `subequations` environment around `align` is used (and then referencing the equations inside the `align`environment)....

Comment: @Deniz Sorry, but `etextools` *is* buggy and its author abandoned it. However I have no problem with `align` in `subequations`.

Comment: @egreg I would like to know more about the bugs in etextools and that it is abondoned. Do you have any references? I know that he once wrote, that it is an experimental package, but I thought it would be proven by use now, as in my tests everything worked flawlessly with the exception of the macro conflict between etoolbox and etextools (which was caused by etoolbox, as etextools was first).

Comment: @PatrickHäcker No, `etextools` came later than `etoolbox` and its biggest defect is trying to “improve” commands from `etoolbox` without ensuring compatibility. Had the developer used different command names, the problem would disappear.

Comment: Yes, `etextools` came later than `etoolbox`, but both packages added more functionality after their first release. I was referring to the definition of `forlistloop`, where both authors [agreed on a solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/VRrFB4ll5n0/jBgtprAe4sAJ), which, unfortunately, does not seem to be implemented up to this day. Anyway, do you know of more conflicting ("improved") macros or how to get such a list?

Comment: @PatrickHäcker I don't really know whether `etextools` implemented `\forlistloop` and `\forcsvlist` before they were introduced in `etoolbox`. But `etextools` has always been marked as “experimental”, so no package author is bound to avoid conflicts with it: actually it's the opposite.

Comment: I try to reach Florent Chervet (the author of etextools) to fix the problem, but I do not know if his address is still valid. In the mean time autonum version 0.3.10 (soon to be on CTAN) basically contains the workaround above. Thanks to all involved for the analysis.

Comment: @PatrickHäcker I've seen the update; never issue `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in a `.sty` file: the declarations are implicit at the beginning and end of it. So the line  `\makeatletter % The missing \makeatother command is on purpose (as every other combination results in an error).` should be removed altogether.

Comment: @PatrickHäcker: I have seen the "GL" (who is imho Florent Chervet) on c.t.t. and f.c.t.t. some days ago.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks a lot for answering. I assume c.t.t and f.c.t.t are mailing lists or something similar. Could you please explain the abbreviations (that's hard for a search engine)? Do you know a valid mail address of him?

Comment: c.t.t is comp.text.tex and f.c.t.t. is fr.comp.text.tex. This are newsgroups. I can see a mail adress in the newsreader but I don't know if it is valid.

Comment: I also mailed him about this very issue. Apart from that `\forlistloop` clash which is easily worked around as @egreg says, there are some really useful macros in `etextools` which fill some holes in a nice expandable way like `\xifempty` etc.

Comment: This solution does not work, and gives `! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'etextools'`

Comment: @JasonGross It seems that now `biblatex` disallows loading `etextools`. You're doomed, sorry.

Comment: The example now needs the `biblatex` option `noerroretextools` to demote the incompatibility error message to a warning.