# Can't compile chemschemex and biblatex in document

Tags: biblatex, chemistry, chemschemex

I am a complete novice to LaTeX and have a problem when compiling my document. Whenever I try turning on `chemschemex` in my document, I get error messages and the document doesn't compile. After testing the packages I have used until now, I think the problem might be with `biblatex` and `chemschemex`. But I don't know why.

I compile using the sequence: `PdfLaTeX`, `BibTeX`, `PdfLaTeX`, `PdfLaTeX`.

I have also enabled `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 %.tex`.

The document compiles for me only if I turn on either `biblatex` or `chemschemex`, but not both at the same time.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,sorting=none,autocite=superscript,giveninits=true,terseinits=false]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{buch,
        Title                    = {Tolles Buch},
        Author                   = {Autor, A.},
        Publisher                = {Verleger},
        Year                     = {2017},
        Edition                  = {1},     
        Location                 = {Berlin}
    }
    }
\end{filecontents}

%\usepackage{chemschemex}



\begin{document}

Dies ist der erste Satz meiner tollen Arbeit.\autocite{buch}
 In diesem Satz verweise ich auf Verbindung %\structref{maleimid}.

%\begin{center}
%   \begin{Chemscheme}
%       \struct[][][scale=1]{maleimid}
%       \RightArrow{\struct[][][scale=1]{cp}}{DEE}
%       \struct[80\,\%][][scale=1]{product}
%   \end{Chemscheme}
%\end{center}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: A blank document with just `\usepackage{biblatex}\usepackage{chemschemex}` in either order also gives an error.  Both times it is `\pdfmatch: repetition-operator operand invalid...Parameters must be numbered consecutively` triggered by `\begin{document}` in this order, or a `\do` statement in `biblatex.sty` in the reverse order.

Comment: `chemschemex` loads `etextools` which seems to be incompatible with `biblatex`…

Comment: @clemens, I have found an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220277/136123) to a previous question regarding `biblatex` and package dependent on `etextools`, which seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @clemens, I think so.  But I don't know how to close or delete my question...

Comment: @user14 users with enough reputation points can vote to close a question (which is better than deleting because then other users with the same problem can still find this question…)

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/669 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/383. Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431965/35864