# Biblatex and newtxmath are not working together

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, newtxmath

I want use `biblatex` and `newtxmath`. But using both gives me following warning `Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'etextools'. \begin{document}` and a number of errors. It seems that `newtxmath` requires `etextools`, and `biblatex` is incompatible. Do I something work or is there a workaround?

MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{newtxmath} %comment this 
\usepackage[]{biblatex}  %or this out to get it working                    

\begin{document}
    Hallo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Update `newtxmath` again. The developer has removed the dependency on `etextools` (this may not be in MikTeX just yet, you may have to wait; but it is definitely in Tex live).

Comment: I just checked that MikTeX still ships the problematic version 1.55 of `newtx`. You'll have another day or two for the update to become available.

Comment: This kind of problems is really fun if you have to submit your thesis. For unknown reasons it worked on my laptop, but my deskop machine complains.

Comment: I suspect that the version on your laptop and desktop machines are different. If you work with several machines, make sure to update all of them at the same time to avoid effects like this. Incompatibilities like this are indeed a big risk if you are facing a deadline. That's why many people would advise not to update if you have to have a document ready in the not-so-distant future. The TeX live documentation says: "[updating packages] is not required, or even necessarily recommended; it's up to you to decide if it makes sense in your particular situation."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As of this morning (UTC, 2018-05-17) this work-around is not needed any more. Both MikTeX and TeX live now ship an updated version of the `newtx` package that does not load `etextools` any more. Update the `newtx` package.

This is a temporary problem with version 1.55 of `newtxmath`. It loads the `etextools` package, which is incompatible with `biblatex`. Version 1.551 released just a few days later removes the dependency on `etextools` and is compatible with `biblatex` again. See also [this discussion on the `tex-live` mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-May/041715.html) for the specifics of this issue as well as  https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/669 and [biblatex and autonum don't work together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220268/35864) for general comments on `etextools` and `biblatex`.

`etextools` (re)defines the macro `\forlistloop` in a way that is incompatible with the original definition from `etoolbox` that `biblatex` expects. (`etextools` is an extension of the ideas of `etoolbox` and if I understand correctly, `etextools` got in first when it comes to defining `\forlistloop`. `etextools` implemented the macro in version 2i dated 2009-08-31, while `etoolbox` defines its `\forlistloop` in version 2.0 dated 2010-08-21.) This is an unfortunate clash of names that can lead to some problems, most notably with `biblatex`. As far as I am aware `etextools` was always considered more of an experimental package than one for production use (see also [package autonum needs the obsolete etex package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285950/35864) and in particular this statement by the package author: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/VRrFB4ll5n0/1IVvhFyKqsAJ)

In the meantime and only with `biblatex` 3.10 or 3.11 you can use

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\oldforlistloop\forlistloop
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\let\forlistloop\oldforlistloop
\usepackage[noerroretextools]{biblatex}                   

\begin{document}
    Hallo
\end{document}
```

as a workaround. **The option `noerroretextools` will probably be removed in future versions of `biblatex`.**

Comment: Hi, why during the compilation I have this error? Package xkeyval Error: `noerroretextools' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'. [\blx@processoptions]

Comment: @Sebastiano In that case your `biblatex` is too old. The option `noerroretextools` was only implemented in version 3.10 of `biblatex` (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/doc/latex/biblatex/CHANGES.md). It will quite probably be removed in future versions of `biblatex`, so don't get used to it!

Comment: I have understood. However +1.

Comment: @tillsten Just remember to remove the workaround as soon as `nextx` is updated (shouldn't take too long).

Comment: Seriously the latex community is really great, but the number of workarounds in my preamble got really freighting.