# fancylabel not incrementing counter if table is include with ltxtable

Tags: numbering, tabularx, input, chemistry, ltxtable

I'm using [`ltxtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) to use flexible width, [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), `X` columns in a long-table. I'm also using the [`chemschemex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemschemex)/[`fancylabel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemschemex) package to give me sweet sweet automatic numbering of my chemical structures.

However, if I include a table containing `\fancylabel[<family>]{label}` commands *via* the `\LTXtable{<width>}{<file>}` method the counter for the fancylabels doesn't increment. And so, all labels end up with the same number.

[image: LTXTable method with incorrect numbering.]

Including the same table, just with the `X` columns substituted for `l` columns, directly in the document or *via* an `\input{}` command gives the correct sequential numbering.

[image: Direct inclusion or <code>\input</code> method with correct numbering.]

None of the inclusion method effects the numbering throughout the document, only that of the table. The table also recognises previously numbered structures and assigns the correct number to them, but then for the next structure fails to change the counter.

[image: body text]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
  \chemsetup{modules = nomenclature}

\let\etoolboxforlistloop\forlistloop % save the good meaning of \forlistloop
\usepackage{chemschemex}
\let\forlistloop\etoolboxforlistloop % restore the good meaning of \forlistloop

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{filecontents}{table.tex}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
      \item [a] A note.
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{%
      @{}%
      >{\bfseries}l<{}%
      >{\collectcell\iupac}X<{\endcollectcell}% This is the column with the tabularx `X` column when using ltxtable
      S%
      @{}%
    }
      \caption{Caption!}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Molecule}} & {\pKa}\\
      \endfirsthead

      \insertTableNotes
      \endlastfoot

      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Pyridines}}                             \\
      \fancylabel[CSX]{pyr}      &  pyridine            &  5.23           \\
      \fancylabel[CSX]{2me-pyr}  &  2-methylpyridine    &  5.97           \\
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Diazines}}                              \\
      \fancylabel[CSX]{pdz}      &  pyridazine          &  2.24\tnote{a}  \\
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Phenols}}                               \\
      \fancylabel[CSX]{phe}      &  phenol              &  9.99           \\
      \fancylabel[CSX]{23me-phe} &  2,3-dimethylphenol  &  10.50          \\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a label: \fancylabel[CSX]{phe}\\
This is an image using chemschemex: \struct[text]{pyr}\\
This is the referenced number for pyridine: \structref{pyr}\\

% No sweet automatic numbering, but at least I get `X` columns.

\afterpage{\clearpage%
    \LTXtable{\linewidth}{table.tex}
}


% Sweet sweet automatic numbering, but no lovely `X` columns.

% \afterpage{\clearpage%
%   \begin{ThreePartTable}
%     \begin{TableNotes}
%       \item [a] A note.
%     \end{TableNotes}
%     \begin{longtable}[c]{%
%       @{}%
%       >{\bfseries}l<{}%
%       >{\collectcell\iupac}l<{\endcollectcell}% This is the column with the tabularx `X` column when using ltxtable
%       S%
%       @{}%
%     }
%       \caption{Caption!}\\
%       \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Molecule}} & {\pKa}\\
%       \endfirsthead
%
%       \insertTableNotes
%       \endlastfoot
%
%       \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Pyridines}}                             \\
%       \fancylabel[CSX]{pyr}      &  pyridine            &  5.23           \\
%       \fancylabel[CSX]{2me-pyr}  &  2-methylpyridine    &  5.97           \\
%       \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Diazines}}                              \\
%       \fancylabel[CSX]{pdz}      &  pyridazine          &  2.24\tnote{a}  \\
%       \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\emph{Phenols}}                               \\
%       \fancylabel[CSX]{phe}      &  phenol              &  9.99           \\
%       \fancylabel[CSX]{23me-phe} &  2,3-dimethylphenol  &  10.50          \\
%     \end{longtable}
%   \end{ThreePartTable}
% }

\end{document}
```

Ideally I'd like to keep the autonumbering of my compounds. There are a few... If I have to remove a feature to get this to work it'll be the `X` columns. I'll replace the `X` column with a `p{}` column. I can determine the width of the p column with a prelininary run through where I include my tables with the `\LTXtable{<width>}{<file>}` command, get the width from thw `.aux` file, and then just use an `\input` command. I'd just rather not have to do this manually for a large document, with potentially many tables.

***Aside***
I know of the conflict between `etoolbox` and `etextools` (and so `autonum` and `fancylabel`) and have implemented the fix [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220277/54688). While the MWE doesn't include `biblatex` my full document does. I've tested the MWE with and without the fix and it makes no difference.

Comment: I'd like to tag chemschemex and fancylabel too, but I don't have enough reputaion to create the tags.

Comment: regarding “sweet sweet automatic numbering of my chemical structures” – do you know the `chemnum` package?

Comment: Hi @clemens! Yes I knew about `chemnum`, but to be honest I hadn't seen how in-depth it went for numbering. I chose`chemschemex` rather than `chemnum`, `chemscheme`, etc. as I wanted to do the auto-numbering *in* the schemes. All my previous attempts with `chemnum` etc. and the `ps-frag` approach failed (I'm using LuaLaTex and fontspec). So, I chose `chemschemex` to try making my schemes. It typesets figures and the numbers with tikz in matrices for auto-numbering and alignment (no `psfrag`). The reason I'm `fancylabel` is because it was written as the slave label package for `chemschemex`.

Comment: I'm not especially attached to `fancylabel`. If I could re-write `chemschemex` to use chemnum instead I would do that. That in itself seems fairly simple as I'd just need to replace the fancyref calls in `chemeschemex`. What is more difficult is that `chemeschemex` uses some `fancyref` internal macros to sort and parse comma-seperated sublabels. Unfortunately I don't know the expl3 syntax, and that'll be where I get stuck, I suspect. I'll read the chemnum documentation to see how I go.

Comment: I learnt `chemfig` instead. With awesome PSfrag replacement. (Provided I used version 15 or earlier of ChemDraw for OSX). I can use included images with `chemfig`, I had though you had to code your structures if you used `chemfig`. It's amazing what you learn when you read the documentation...

Comment: I might cite your last sentence once in while :)