# Double bibliography and bold authors: 1) partial biblio with bold author 2) complete biblio with no bold author

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bold, author

in writing my PhD thesis, I would like LaTeX to produce two bibliographies as follows:

1. In the initial overview chapter I would like to produce a biblio that contains only the works authored by myself, with my name in bold. More precisely I would like to print all my works with a given keyword (from the .bib file), and then all my works with a second given keyword (from the .bib file).
2. At the end of my thesis I would like all references to appear, including mine, but without any bold name.

As of now my main issue is that both bibliographies end up with my name in bold. I am using bib latex with biber and xpatch to get my name in bold. A snapshot of this is in the following, where I replace `<insertheremyhash>` with the hash associated by biber to my name.

Thanks a lot!

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true, defernumbers=false,citetracker=true,maxnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false, noerroretextools=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio_thesis_2.bib}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}%
}
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}{{<insertheremyhash>}}
```

**EDIT: ADDED MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, headsepline, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest1.bib}
@BOOK{BookMe1,
  author    = {Me Me},
  title     = {Paper for first part},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
  Keywords  = {minepart1}
}
@BOOK{BookMe2,
  author    = {Me Me},
  title     = {Paper for second part},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
  Keywords  = {minepart2}
}
@BOOK{Bookothers1,
  author    = {Someone else},
  title     = {Someone else work},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}


% == Bibliography ================================================
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true, defernumbers=false,citetracker=true,maxnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false, noerroretextools=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatextest1.bib}


% GETTING Me Me to appear in bold
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}%
}
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{0e4113c11a30770aa5d2e0f481425c95}}



\begin{document}

% OVERVIEW CHAPTER
\section*{Overview}
\nocite{BookMe1,BookMe2,Bookothers1}
Part I of this thesis is based on the following works.
% print partial biblio relative to part 1 + bold
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ydnt]
\defbibfilter{filt_minepart1}{ keyword=minepart1 }
\printbibliography[filter=filt_minepart1,heading=none,title=none]
\end{refcontext}


Part II of this thesis is based on the following works.
% print partial biblio relative to part 2 + bold
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ydnt]
\defbibfilter{filt_minepart2}{ keyword=minepart2 }
\printbibliography[filter=filt_minepart2,heading=none,title=none]
\end{refcontext}

% print full biblio, no bold!
%backmatter
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a fully working example document with a few example entries (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Edit: added MWE

Comment: PSA: The option `noerroretextools` is very likely going to be removed in future versions and will be replaced with a more primitive mechanism, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/751. In the MWE there is absolutely no reason to use the option and you get a warning that discourages its use.

Comment: @moewe: you are right about the use of `noerroretextools`. Nevertheless in the full document I am using also the package `autonum` which is known to be incompatible with bib latex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220268/biblatex-and-autonum-dont-work-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All commands involved can be used locally since they don't need global assignments. That means we can pack the commands responsible for bold author name up into a macro (called `\makenamesbold` below) that we can then use whenever we want a specific bibliography to have your name in bold.

In the MWE it is enough to simply issue the command within the `refcontext` because that gives the necessary grouping, but you could also use `\AtNextBibliography`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=alphabetic,
            sorting=nyt, giveninits=true, defernumbers=false,
            citetracker=true, maxnames=99, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand*{\boldnamedo}[1]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{#1}
    {\bfseries\listbreak}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{name:bold}{%
  \forlistloop{\boldnamedo}{\boldnames}}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{0e4113c11a30770aa5d2e0f481425c95}}

\newcommand*{\makenamesbold}{%
  \xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{BookMe1,
  author    = {Me Me},
  title     = {Paper for first part},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
  Keywords  = {minepart1}
}
@BOOK{BookMe2,
  author    = {Me Me},
  title     = {Paper for second part},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
  Keywords  = {minepart2}
}
@BOOK{Bookothers1,
  author    = {Someone else},
  title     = {Someone else work},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Overview}
\nocite{BookMe1,BookMe2,Bookothers1}
Part I of this thesis is based on the following works.
% print partial biblio relative to part 1 + bold
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ydnt]
\makenamesbold
\defbibfilter{filt_minepart1}{ keyword=minepart1 }
\printbibliography[filter=filt_minepart1,heading=none,title=none]
\end{refcontext}


Part II of this thesis is based on the following works.
% print partial biblio relative to part 2 + bold
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ydnt]
\makenamesbold
\defbibfilter{filt_minepart2}{ keyword=minepart2 }
\printbibliography[filter=filt_minepart2,heading=none,title=none]
\end{refcontext}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The two overview bibliographies with "M. Me" in bold]

[image: Full bibliography on page 3 with no bold names]