# Conflict between subfiles, bm and newtxtext

Tags: bold, subfiles, newtxmath

I have a document made up of many sub-documents. These documents can be compiled separately using LaTeX and the `subfiles` package but not when I use both `newtxtext` and `bm` as well. How can I overcome this?

For example, file `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{sub1}
\end{document}
```

File `sub1.tex` in the same directory:

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
$\bm{x}$
\end{document}
```

The main file compiles without a problem, but trying to compile sub1 by itself reports an error but only when `newtxtext` is included.

The log file tells me

```
Runaway argument?
{document}\ifx \reserved@a \@currenvir \else \@badend {document}\fi  \clearpage 
\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \reserved@a.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> \input sub1.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> \input sub1.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

Adding a paragraph break between `$\bm{x}$` and the `\end{document}` gives the message

```
! Paragraph ended before \bm@test@token was complete.
```

Searching for this message brings up the question [Package incompatibilites: etoolbox, hyperref, and bm, standalone?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22995/package-incompatibilites-etoolbox-hyperref-and-bm-standalone). Could this be a similar problem?

Adding `\listfiles` gives

```
 *File List*
   report.cls    2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
   size10.clo    2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option)
newtxtext.sty    2014/04/26 v1.27
 fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
  xkeyval.sty    2006/11/18 v2.5f package option processing (HA)
  xkeyval.tex    2006/11/18 v2.5f key=value parser (HA)
 etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
     etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  fontenc.sty
    t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
   ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
newtxmath.sty    2014/04/26 v1.27
  amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
  amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
   amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
   amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
   amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   binhex.tex
       bm.sty    2004/02/26 v1.1c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
 subfiles.sty    2012/05/23 Federico Garcia
 verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 omlntxmi.fd    2012/03/22 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
 omsntxsy.fd    2012/11/14 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OMS/ntxsy.
  untxexa.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
   ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1ntxrx.fd    2012/12/25 v1.0
    sub1.tex
  untxmia.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
  untxsya.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsya.
  untxsyb.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyb.
  untxsyc.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
  ***********
```

After installing the latest TeX Live and removing my previously installed packages, the error remains and the log file gives

```
 *File List*
 report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
 size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
newtxtext.sty    2014/04/07 v1.25
fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
 fontenc.sty
  t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
newtxmath.sty    2014/04/07 v1.25
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  binhex.tex
      bm.sty    2004/02/26 v1.1c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
subfiles.sty    2012/05/23 Federico Garcia
verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
omlntxmi.fd    2012/03/22 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
omsntxsy.fd    2012/11/14 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OMS/ntxsy.
 untxexa.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 t1ntxrx.fd    2012/12/25 v1.0
    sub1.tex
 untxmia.fd    2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
 untxsya.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsya.
 untxsyb.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyb.
 untxsyc.fd    2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
 ***********
```

Inspired by the question [Package incompatibilites: etoolbox, hyperref, and bm, standalone?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22995/package-incompatibilites-etoolbox-hyperref-and-bm-standalone), in `etoolbox.sty` I commented out

```
\patchcmd\enddocument
  {\deadcycles}
  {\let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@afterenddocumenthook
   \deadcycles}
  {}
  {\let\etb@@end\@@end
   \def\@@end{%
     \let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
     \@afterenddocumenthook
     \etb@@end}}
{<environment>}{<code>}
```

This allows `sub1.tex` to be compiled on its own without error. This suggests that there is a conflict of the type described in the linked question.

Comment: Sorry, but I get no error.

Comment: I get no error with a blank line after `$\bm{x}$` either.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to reproduce the problem. Could you share you log file so that I can compare it with mine? The fact that you can't reproduce it suggests there is a problem with my installation of the packages but the fact that the main file compiles as expected suggests otherwise.

Comment: Please, add `\listfiles` to your main document and report the relevant part of the .log file you get.

Comment: You have an old TeX distribution (`report.cls` has been last changed on 2007/10/19 and `amsmath.sty` on 2013/01/14, for instance). Adding the most recent version of `newtx` and `subfiles` to such an old distribution can expose to all kinds of problems. Update your TeX distribution, which seems to be eight years old.

Comment: I have installed the latest TeX Live distribution and the error remains. I have added the listfiles output.

Comment: Now the file list is the same, but I don't get any error.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to where the problem might be?

Comment: Sorry, no. An extraneous invisible character?

Comment: I do think it is a reproducible problem. I did a full install of TeX Live on a different computer. The only things I did were to install TeX Live and make the example files described. Running latex main.tex gives no problem. Running latex sub1.tex gives the error described.

Comment: The problem seems to be in `newtxtext`.

Answer (score 5):

the `newtxtext` package  loads `etoolbox` package which redefines `\@@end`. It *really* shouldn't do that. Since it does you can do this to locally restore it.

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@@@@@end\@@end
\def\fixend{\let\@@end\@@@@@@end}
\makeatother
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
$\fixend\bm{x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that it's `etoolbox` that redefines `\@@end`

Comment: @JosephWright is it? OK thanks I'll re-apportion blame:-)

Comment: Notice the patch: `\patchcmd\enddocument
  {\deadcycles}
  {\let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@afterenddocumenthook
   \deadcycles}
  {}
  {\let\etb@@end\@@end
   \def\@@end{%
     \let\AfterEndDocument\@firstofone
     \@afterenddocumenthook
     \etb@@end}}` only alters `\@@end`  if the initial patch of `\enddocument` fails.

Comment: @JosephWright presumably subfiles has made "only inside end document" to be rather more places:-)

Comment: Slight correction: it only makes the change to `\@@end` if `\enddocument` has been altered, which is what happens with `subfiles`.